# Needing to deploy a controller into Cloud Services rather than Websites, best approach

Tags: azure, azure-storage

My MVC3 / SQL Azure runs great on Windows Azure WebSites. However there is one feature, implemented by one controller which creates a PDF document. This, I have now found out, is not allowed on WebSites, since the component I use, and many similar access GDI natively. In essence, it requires full trust. This component works fine on Cloud Services, I guess as a Web Role. I am following advice from the supplier here. However I do not want to port my entire application across, so I have come up with the idea of creating one webRole for this specific controller. It accesses the same SQL Azure instance as the WebSites install.

So my question is what would be the simplest approach to implement this as a standalone service on WACS which would then be called via the main Web Application on WAWS? Also one should not be able to access this WACS directly from a URL. It is like a child controller of that in the WAWS hosted application.

Thanoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1-)create a WCF and host it in Cloud Services (Web Role).

2-)create another aspnet mvc web application and copy just this controller and publish it to cloud services.

Comment: Thanks for this. The parent application requires the user to be authenticated and in fact uses membership services. What is the best wat to call across to option 2) within an authenticated context ie a stranger would not be able to access child.cloudapp.net directly, they would have to login into parent.azurewebsites.net first. Would I use a server redirect or an iframe ?? BTW i am opting for 2) simply because I know MVC, and have no experience with WCF.

Comment: You`ll have to customize your authentication process to allow both apps use the same cookie. Doing that you`ll get what you want.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. I guess I need to raise another question on this authentication issue, as I am still a little confused on how to achieve what you suggest. However thank you for answering this question